# Why is this code only running twice

Tags: delphi

I have this code that only runs twice with the variables
DateStart := 27-01-2013
DateStop  := 31-03-2013

I think it should run with the results of 31-01-2013, 28-02-2013 and 31-3-2013
But I only get 2 results

I am quite sure I have been gazing to much and can't see the problem

```
begin
  DateStart := EndOfTheMonth(DateStart);
  while DateStart <= DateStop do
    begin
      FsFutureCreate(DateStart, cxDebit.Value, cxKredit.Value, aAccount, aType, aStore, aCity, txtText.Text, lRecord);
      DateStart := EndOfTheMonth(IncMonth(DateStart));
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It never occurred to you to do some debugging? (Like adding `ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(DateStart) + '  vs  ' + DateTimeToStr(DateStop))` to the body of the loop?)

Comment: Andreas is right. Don't be helpless. When faced with a problem like this, add some debugging output, or just step through with the debugger. Look at the values of the local variables as the loop executes. You would immediately have noticed that `DateStart` was a non-integer value.

Comment: I have had 
    ShowMessage(DateToStr(DateStart) + sLineBreak + DateToStr(DateStop));
put in so many places to try to figure out what could be wrong

Comment: DateStart and DateStop are defined as TDate so the timepart should i theory be 0

Comment: @OZ8HP: Well, both `TDate`, `TTime`, and `TDateTime` are actually `double`s, and no RTL function makes any distinction between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Either* `FsFutureCreate` (which you never told us what it is) has some side-effects, *or* you have some issue with floating-point fuzz. As you know, date and time values are doubles, and so comparisons like `<=` are dangerous. (Especially if you disregard the time part, as my analysis below shows.)

The second one is the more likely one. I just tried

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var d: TDate; d2: TDate;
begin
  d := EncodeDate(2013, 01, 31);
  d := IncMonth(d);                          // 2013-02-28
  d := EndOfTheMonth(d);                     // 2013-02-28
  d := IncMonth(d);                          // 2013-03-28
  d := EndOfTheMonth(d);                     // 2013-03-31

  d2 := EncodeDate(2013, 03, 31);

  // d is now 2013-03-31 23:59:59
  // d2 is now 2013-03-31 00:00:00

  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(d <= d2, true));

end;
```

and got `false`, as one would expect. Hence, the problem, in this case, is that the `EndOfTheMonth` function also sets the time to the last second (or millisec) of the day. But even if this wasn't the case, doing comparisons using = is dangerous when it comes to floating-point values.

To fix your comparison, do

```
CompareDate(d, d2) <= 0
```

instead of

```
d <= d2.
```

I leave it as an exercise to find out, [using the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.CompareDate), why this works and is robust.

Comment: The easiest fix (when you're not using the time portion of a `TDateTime` is to truncate before comparing as in `Trunc(d) <= Trunc(d2)`.

Comment: @Ken That's right. I'd do the same when assigning `DateStart` as well because we may want it after the loop terminates. But I'd say that `DateOf` is better than `Trunc` in terms of conveying meaning to the reader of the code.

Comment: Indeed. Nedless to say, `DateOf` is implemented as a plain `trunc`.

Comment: @David: Probably true. But `DateOf` simply does a `Trunc` anyway, and it's one less function call. (I know it's not really of importance any more, but old habits die hard. <g>)

Comment: Hm... Why isn't it `inline`d?

Comment: @Ken Given that `DateOf` is inlined, the resulting code will be identical. Readability and clarity is the most important thing when taking a decision like that.

Comment: @David: Just checked in Delphi 2009, and it isn't inlined.

Comment: @David: It's not inlined in D2007 either, and as far as clarity, every Delphi developer I've ever known understands that `TDateTime` is a double and that `Trunc` zeros the time portion. I don't think there's any clarity lost here especially (but I did say "Probably true" in my last comment to you - that's agreement).

Comment: Just for the record
FsFutureCreate is a procedure that wirtes a record to a database for each date found in the loop.
And I ended using Trunc and got the result I wanted
I may have been tired when writing the code and forgetting to check that EndOfTheMonth returns both date and time
And now all that is left is to find methods that gives LastWorkingDate and not EndOfTheMonth but that is another issue

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `EndOfTheMonth` gives you the last day of the month, but also a time corresponding to the end of the day. But your `DateStop` is probably the very beginning of the  day.

If you print out the raw values of `DateStart` and `DateStop` in the loop you see this:

```
41333.9999999884 41364
41364.9999999884 41364
```

So, looking at the final line you can see we have a time of 23:59 on day 41364.

I'd fix this by working with pure dates and not letting time get in the way of things. Change the incrementing code to remove the time part of the date. And I'd also be explicit about doing the same in the loop test.

```
while DateOf(DateStart) <= DateOf(DateStop) do
begin
  ....
  DateStart := DateOf(EndOfTheMonth(IncMonth(DateStart)));
end;
```

Comment: +1. Perhaps it is better to use `DateOf`.